# add a char to a string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, cs50

I have this function called `add_to_string` and I call it from my main function to add a char to a string

```
add_to_string(name[I]);
```

it seems to me that I cannot append a char into a string. so how would I tackle this problem?

my main intention in this code is simply to print the entered name initials and avoid the user wrong entry (adding two spaces between first name and middle name)

here is my full code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

string add_to_string (char letter);
string result;

int main (void) 
{
    printf("pleas enter your full name:  ");
    string name = get_string();
    int len = strlen(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) 
            {
                add_to_string(name[i]);
            } else if (name[i] == ' ')
            {
                if (name[i + 1] != ' ')
                {
                add_to_string(name[i]);
                }
            }
    }

    printf("%s\n",result);
}

string add_to_string (char letter)
{

    strncat(result, letter, 30);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled... You have several misuses and type errors that any decent compiler will highlight right away.

Comment: I don't really get what you meant, but I suppose you mean the string and get_string() ,, this is a class am taking and they provide us with this cs50 header that include these types and functions

Comment: e.g. [man strncat](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat): `char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);`. What is the type of the second param and what is the type you gave it?

Comment: this is my entire question haha , I know it expect a string, but what if I have to add char? what would I do?

Comment: What kaylum said for one. My problem with cs50 is that they foster this approach of typdefing for no real useful abstraction. You would have learned far more by simply knowing you are working with `char*` than `string`.

Comment: You can't give single character like that, really. C lets you pass `char`, it does a not very useful conversion, and your program has a hidden error that you now languish over.

Comment: If you need to add a single character, cheat. Plase it in an array of length 2, the character itself being at index 0, and the `'\0'` being at index 1, and pass that to the function.

Comment: Another big problem is that `string result;` declares a `NULL` pointer. You can't access that pointer. You need to allocate memory for it first.

Comment: `typedef char * string;`. Everyone can do that. This `string` type is really misleading.

Comment: To expand on @Jean-FrançoisFabre's comment, a "string" is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". A pointer of type `char*` may or may not *point* to a string (i.e., point to its initial character), but it cannot *be* a string. I understand that you're stuck with this typedef, because it's provided by `<cs50.h>`, but be aware that it's misleading.

Comment: thank you guys,, after a little of research I found out what you mean, cuz at first I didn't study what a pointer is, so I got so confused with of what you were saying

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what `string` is here but I assume it is a typedef for `char*`

Your function

```
string add_to_string (char letter)
{
  strncat(result, letter, 30);
  return result;
}
```

is wrong in several ways,

first `result` is a global variable so initially it is pointing to NULL.

you need to allocate storage for your string and let `result` point to that storage or declare `result` as an array

```
char result[128]; // assuming here it is still global otherwise initialize
```

The function `add_to_string` adds a character to the string but you call `strncat` which expects two strings as arguments plus a size.

Instead append the character like this

```
size_t len = strlen(result)
result[ len++ ] = letter;
result[ len ] = '\0';
```

This keeps `result` a string